# How to create a Microsoft custom voice through the API or SDK

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am evaluating Microsoft Custom Voice as a potential vendor and want to know how to programmatically create and train custom voices either through an API or SDK.

After an extensive search, I have only found documentation showing how to create a custom voice through their custom voice portal. There is one line in this page that hints at a custom voice training API.

Below is that passage and the link to that documentation page.

Could you help me either figure out how to do this or confirm that no such API exists?

> Once you have prepared your data, you can start to upload them to the
>   Custom Voice portal, or through the Custom Voice training API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-voice-create-voice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess George's answer is not relevant as you are specially talking of "Custom" voice / speech.

### Link to the APIs

There are APIs for this part but the documentation is not clear, you are right. You can find at https://westus.cris.ai/swagger/ui/index the API and available operations. Note that it exits in several regions, for example West Europe is https://westeurope.cris.ai/swagger/ui

[image: api capture]

Currently, this page points to Speech 2.0 API but it looks like there will be a 3.0 from Microsoft soon. As you can see if you look at the network calls from the Speech portal ([link](https://speech.microsoft.com/portal/)), they are in fact already using this 3.0 api (preview):

[image: api 3.0 used in portal]

### How to use them?

You can have a look to the process by doing it through the portal and checking what is called on the API side.

Here is an overview of the process:

1. Create your dataset for model training, using `/datasets/upload` operation
2. Once your dataset has been processed successfully, create a model using a POST request to `/models` (see operation [here](https://westus.cris.ai/swagger/ui/index#/Custom%20Speech%20endpoints%3A/CreateEndpoint)). This POST has several details in the body: base model, training dataset used etc. It is this operation which will train your model, you don't need another call to start the training
3. Once training is completed (you can check the status using GET on `/models` or a specific GET using the model ID to `/models/yourModelId`), you can "deploy" it. For that, you have to create an endpoint based on this model: it is a POST to `/endpoints`s (see operation [here](https://westus.cris.ai/swagger/ui/index#/Custom%20Speech%20endpoints%3A/CreateEndpoint))
4. Then you can monitor the deployment status by calling GET on `/endpoints` or GET by ID, like for models

Comment: which endpoint would be used to download the "Voice Data" or "Transcripts" from the uploaded Dataset? If I upload a long audio and may want to download the generated utterances and its transcripts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "generated utterances and its transcripts"? It is not automatically splitting and transcribing your audio if this is what you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nicolas, using MS Speech Portal it does automatically splits long audio into small utterances and returns its corresponding transcriptions when we upload Long audio + transcript, here's the description from the Speech Portal - "A collection (.zip) of long, unsegmented audio files (.wav or .mp3, longer than 20 seconds), paired with a transcript (.txt) containing all of the spoken words."

Comment: After the processing we get the option to download the utterances with its broken transcriptions, I have used it at least 10-15 times but I was thinking if this process could be automated using their API's, anyways thanks for the swagger URL, I hope I could find something there, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the API and the SDK, they are all in the doc.

Here is the [Text-to-speech rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech), if you want the sdk you could go to this doc:[About the Speech SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk).

And about how to create custom voice, need an Azure account and a Speech service subscription, further more information, you could refer to this doc:[Get started with Custom Voice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-voice).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking specifically for creating a voice, uploading audio to it, and triggering the training job programmatically. I don't want to have to go through the custom voice portal.

I have only been able to find documentation on how to generate audio clips from the voice once it has already been created.

Comment: In the document there is not much sample, if you want samples you could refer to this github project.https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk